# Parsing ugly html with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping ice data for Lake Mendota from [https://www.aos.wisc.edu/~sco/lakes/Mendota-ice.html](https://www.aos.wisc.edu/%7Esco/lakes/Mendota-ice.html). I wrote a scraper that works but I am curious if the code can be cleaned.

Here is a representative snippet from the HTML. Sometimes the data you want is before a 
 and sometimes it is after a `<br\>`.

```
     <td align="center" valign="TOP" width="12%">
      <p>
       <font face="Arial,Helvetica" size="2">
        2010-11
        <br/>
        2011-12
        <br/>
        2012-13
        <br/>
        2013-14
        <br/>
        2014-15
        <br/>
        2015-16
        <br/>
        2016-17
        <br/>
        2017-18
        <br/>
        2018-19
        <br/>
        "
        <br/>
        2019-20
        <br/>
        2020-21
       </font>
      </p>
     </td>
```

Here is a function I wrote to scrape the data. I look before each `<br/>` to get the data and use some logic to look after the last one. I am also using too many for loops. Yes, the code works, but this is not good looking code and that is also important

Ideally, I would like to just get what is between the font tags and split along `<br/>`. I struggled to do that and ended up with a mess of `\n` `\r` and `\xa0` characters.

The code below is what happens when you brute force a solution.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
    
def get_mendota_data():
    # read html
    url = 'https://www.aos.wisc.edu/~sco/lakes/Mendota-ice.html'
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = r.text

    # create soup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    # gets headers
    headers = []
    match = soup.find('table')
    for cell in match.find_all('td'):
        try:
            val = cell.p.text.strip()
            headers.extend([val])
        # duplicated, break out at blank space
        except Exception as e:
            break

    # this used to put data into default_dict
    len_headers_minus_one = len(headers)-1
    
    # default dict to store data
    d = defaultdict(list)

    # outside loop over headers
    num=0 
    for match in soup.find_all('table'):
        for col in  match.find_all('tr'): 
            for val in col.find_all('font'):
                val_list = []
                for enum, br in enumerate(val.find_all('br'), start=1):
                    try:

                        # see if data before the <br/>
                        next_s = br.previousSibling.strip()

                        # make sure not empty string ''
                        if len(next_s)>0:
                            val_list.extend([next_s])

                        # see if data behind the last <br/>
                        if (enum==len(val.find_all('br'))) and len(br.nextSibling.strip())>0:
                            next_s = br.nextSibling.strip()
                            val_list.extend([next_s])
                    except:
                        pass
                
                # make sure list contains data
                if len(val_list)>0:
                    # puts val_list into dict 
                    d[headers[num]].extend(val_list)
                    # and updates num
                    if num<len_headers_minus_one:
                        num = num +1
                    else:
                        num=0

    # conver to tdataframe 
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(d))
```

You can run the function like this

```
df = get_mendota_data()
```

Any ideas to efficiently scrape this data will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## Update

I learned about stripped_strings and was able to clean up the code substantially. This is as clean as I can make it, but would love to get rid of the nested for loops

```py
def get_mendota_data():
    # read html
    url = 'https://www.aos.wisc.edu/~sco/lakes/Mendota-ice.html'
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = r.text

    # create soup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    # soup.find('table') gets all the first table
    # but I know the first four are the headers
    headers = [val for val in soup.find('table').stripped_strings][0:4]

    # initate a dictionary to store data
    def_dict = defaultdict(list)

    for match in soup.find_all('tr'):
        col_list = [] # will store all the columns 
        for font in match.find_all('font'):
            tmp_list = [data for data in font.stripped_strings]

            # append to col_list
            if len(tmp_list)>0:
                col_list.append(tmp_list)

        # put first half in dict
        for enum, col in enumerate(col_list[0:4]):
            def_dict[headers[enum]].extend(col)

        # put second half in def_dict
        for enum, col in enumerate(col_list[4:]):
            def_dict[headers[enum]].extend(col)


    # conver to tdataframe 
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(def_dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a very confusingly designed page, but extracting the data was an interesting task. I decided to use xpath and list comprehensions to get there:

```
import lxml.html as lh
doc = lh.fromstring(r.text)

entries = []
targets = doc.xpath('//table//tr')

for target in targets:
    subs = target.xpath('.//td')
    del subs[4] #this one is an empty column
    entries.extend([[s.strip() for s in sub.xpath('.//*/text()')] for sub in subs])

#some trailing empty elements needed to be removed before proceeding
entries = [[list(filter(lambda x: x != "", entry)) for entry in entries[r::4]] for r in range(4)]

#unpack to the correct columns
[Winter,Closed,Opened,Days] = [[x for list in entry for x in list] for entry in entries]

#and now create a dataframe:
final = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Winter,Closed,Opened,Days)),
               columns =['Winter', 'Closed',"Opened","Days"])
final
```

The output is the 176 winter days with opening and closing events:

```
    Winter   Closed     Opened  Days
0   1852-53     ---     5 Apr   ---
1   1853-54     27 Dec  ---     ---
2   1854-55     ---     ---     ---
3   1855-56     18 Dec  14 Apr  118
4   1856-57     6 Dec   6 May   151
```

etc.